# Azure API Management - Subscription keys for Applications?

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-api-management

I've been playing around with API Management and it looks great. The only issue I have is that when calling an API you need to pass a subscription key, which is linked to a 'User'. In the majority of use cases the caller of our APIs are Applications (back-end services).

Am I supposed to be creating a User account per Application, or is there another way for me to obtain a security key for the App?

I have had a brief look at AD, however I don't want to go down that route straight away.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a single "API Consumer" user and use the key assigned to that user for all your back end services.  Or you could create a separate user for each of your services.  But creating a separate user you would have the ability to independently revoke access to certain services and control rate limiting/quotas independently.

Comment: Thanks. It still seems wrong to create a user, but I guess that is the expected implementation..

Comment: @StrictlySocial I think you make a good point.  If you could add it as an issue here http://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management that would be great.

Comment: Is there a way to assign a subscription to a service principal? And maybe use the secret of the service principal instead of the subscription key?